# getElementByClassName for dynamically created elements

Tags: javascript, html, class, dynamic

I've created some divs dynamically with javascript:

```
<div class="tile"></div>
<div class="tile"></div>
<div class="tile"></div>
<div class="tile"></div>
```

Now I want to select these divs and change their dimensions like so:

```
var singleTiles = document.getElementsByClassName('tile');
singleTiles.style.width = '10px';
singleTiles.style.height = '10px';
```

But this doesn't seem to work. I'm assuming because the elements were added dynamically. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: singleTiles is an array so you have to itterate over it

Comment: I believe it's actually a `HTMLCollection` which is `live`, not that it will matter in this example but can in other situations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**document.getElementsByClassName**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName), it returns an array of all child elements which have any of the given class names. Here elements is a `HTMLCollection` of found elements. So you have to loop through it.

Use

```
var singleTiles = document.getElementsByClassName('tile');
for(var i=0; i<singleTiles.length; i++) { 
    singleTiles[i].style.width = '10px';
    singleTiles[i].style.height = '10px';
}
```

Comment: why can't i call . join() on the resulting array?

Comment: @dandavis, I have not tried that and As per my understanding Here we are refering to DOM elements So i don't think that will work

Comment: then please edit the part about " it returns an array " so as to not confuse noobs.